# I would like the search bar to follow as i scroll

Tags: html, searchbar

I am having a problem. I am doing a website for someone, and they would like me to have the search bar to follow as they scroll and I can't for the life of me get it right pls help me.
Cheers, Justin.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH3vV.png)

Comment: CSS `position: fixed` / `position: sticky`

Comment: Whichever you choose (sticky or fixed), don't forget you need CSS `top: 0` for both of them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by positioning the search bar input.

```css
#myInput {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

And then the HTML will look like this

```html
<nav id="myInput">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search For Names">
</nav>
```

Since the search box is inside the div with the navbar `id`, I'll suggest you position the navbar instead. Here's the codepen to see how this works [example](https://codepen.io/evavic44/pen/PoRbZze)

Comment: Hi, you can add the codepen directly in your message thanks to snippet ! :)

Comment: Oh... Thanks. @Elikill58 I just wanted to illustrate the fixed position during scrolling.